# Interviewing at other places after accepting a job offer

Tags: interviewing, entry-level

So I am graduating in May and have accepted a job offer at a company. The contract that I signed for them said I (or the employer) can end my employment at any time, for any reason. Although since this company is not my ideal job and I have continued to apply to other places.

I recently got invited to my final rounds at another company, however they want to do a background check. They specifically said they will call past employers. The problem is the job I accepted I also interned at so they would call them.

The company I have my final rounds with would definitely be a better fit for what I am looking for. The problem is the location is not ideal. Thus, I am not even sure if I would accept the position if I got the offer. The company already booked my plane ticket as well as hotel.

**My question is should I consent to the background check and risk the company I already accepted at finding out and revoking my offer.** If I choose not to interview how bad will it look that they wasted money on getting me a plane ticket as well as hotel (not sure if they can get a refund).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: **Just because you can doesn't mean you should.**

Comment: There is no risk. In the extremely unlikely event you are challenged on this just blame slow admin by the second company. They don't know when you gave consent for the check.If you choose not to attend any subsequent interview just let the company know within a reasonable timeframe. They don't have the Presidential Suite already booked on a non-refund basis for the use of you and your entourage.

Comment: @TheMathemagician thanks for the advice, I hadn't really thought of that. If they question me I can always say that was before I accepted the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they require a background check before hiring you, they will need to do a background check before hiring you.

Needing to do a background check before the interview seems unlikely.  I would contact whoever is arranging your interview and explain that you have an offer from a company you interned for and would prefer they not contact them, and that you will sign the release for the background check once they have made an offer.

Comment: Thanks I will try emailing the recruiter and see what they say about that. I guess simply saying that I have an offer and leaving out the part that I accepted would work best.